# Apply css to each last n row in table depending on the size of its table head (mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I work with a plugin which generated html tables. I need to add apply CSS for each LAST n-element of the table, depending on the amount of items in the first row. I have to do it for mobile view.

I am allowed to use jQuery and Javascript.

For example, my desktop table looks like this:
[image: desktop]

And depending on the size of elements in thead, I should apply CSS to each n-element in mobile table:
[image: mobile]

How can I calculate this n-number and apply style only for these n-elements?
In addition, the number of th's may vary (from 3 to 6) so I should make this code adaptive.
Hope someone can help me!

upd:
code example of mobile table

```
<table className="mytable mobile">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th1</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th2</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th3</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th4</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td4</span></td>
    </tr>
    .....
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my desktop table with thead elements:

```
<table class="mytable desktop">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>th1</th>
                            <th>th2</th>
                            <th>th3</th>
                            <th>th4</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>td1</td>
                            <td>td2</td>
                            <td>td3</td>
                            <td>td4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>td1</td>
                            <td>td2</td>
                            <td>td3</td>
                            <td>td4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>td1</td>
                            <td>td2</td>
                            <td>td3</td>
                            <td>td4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>td1</td>
                            <td>td2</td>
                            <td>td3</td>
                            <td>td4</td>
                        </tr>
                        ....
                    </table>
```

Comment: Add Code HTML & CSS

Comment: @LaljiTadhani added HTML

Answer (score 0):

Add `nth:child` CSS like `nth-child(4n)`

```css
.mobile tr:nth-child(4n){
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable mobile">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th1</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th2</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th3</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th4</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td4</span></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th1</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th2</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th3</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th4</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td4</span></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th1</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th2</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td className="key"><span>it was th3</span></td>
        <td className="val"><span>td3</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, this solution won't work for me because tr:nth-child(4n) has fixed number which is 4. It will work for this exact table, but I need somehow to make this number calculated. It should be calculated depending on the amount of elements in thead of my desktop table.

Comment: @Aftermaz I have added onther answer

Answer (score 0):

Use This Way no need any other table

```css
table#customDataTable{
width:100%;}
table#customDataTable th{text-align:left;}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  table#customDataTable caption {
    background-image: none;
  }
  table#customDataTable thead {
    display: none;
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody td {
    display: block;
    padding: .6rem;
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody tr td:first-child {
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody tr td:first-child a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody tr td:first-child:before {
    color: rgb(225, 181, 71);
  }
  table#customDataTable tbody td:before {
    content: attr(data-th);
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10rem;
  }
  table#customDataTable tr th:last-child,
  table#customDataTable tr td:last-child {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    min-width: 100px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="customDataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-th="#">1</td>
      <td data-th="Firstname">Anna</td>
      <td data-th="Lastname">Pitt</td>
      <td data-th="Age">35</td>
      <td data-th="City">New York</td>
      <td data-th="Country">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-th="#">1</td>
      <td data-th="Firstname">Anna</td>
      <td data-th="Lastname">Pitt</td>
      <td data-th="Age">35</td>
      <td data-th="City">New York</td>
      <td data-th="Country">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-th="#">1</td>
      <td data-th="Firstname">Anna</td>
      <td data-th="Lastname">Pitt</td>
      <td data-th="Age">35</td>
      <td data-th="City">New York</td>
      <td data-th="Country">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-th="#">1</td>
      <td data-th="Firstname">Anna</td>
      <td data-th="Lastname">Pitt</td>
      <td data-th="Age">35</td>
      <td data-th="City">New York</td>
      <td data-th="Country">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-th="#">1</td>
      <td data-th="Firstname">Anna</td>
      <td data-th="Lastname">Pitt</td>
      <td data-th="Age">35</td>
      <td data-th="City">New York</td>
      <td data-th="Country">USA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank u so much for your efforts, but still it doesn't solve my problem :(